# Set CSS style for table

Tags: css

I have several tables in HTML page. But for every table I would like to apply different CSS style. If I use this code I will apply the style for every table.

```
th, td {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

How I can apply the style just for one table?

I tried this

```
.intro{
    th, td {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 7px;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        /*    margin: 10px;*/
    }}
```

Comment: This is basic CSS. Did you even tried to google it?

Comment: Use a `class` or `id` for the required table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `class` or `id` for the required table. Check below example.

```css
.mystyle th,
.mystyle td {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<b><i>Only this table will have the specified styles</i></b>
<table class="mystyle">
  <tr>
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <th>Title 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<b><i>This table doesn't inherit the styles</i></b>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <th>Title 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each table needs to be given a unique class and then can be targeted specifically.

HTML:

```
<table class="first">
    <!--table elements-->
</table>
<table class="second">
    <!--table elements-->
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.first th, table.first td{
    /*properties*/
}
table.second th, table.second td{
    /*properties*/
}
```